# Is my dry aged beef spoiled?

Tags: dry-aging

I cut out 30 days dry aged prime rib into pieces and then put in a vacuum seal bag and froze them. I found these brownish spots on the inside of each piece. Is this normal or they are spoiled?

[image: [1]]

I dry aged them by myself. Temperature is around 2-4 degree Celsius and humidity level is around 80%. The outer layer that I trimmed off seemed a little oily, not slimmy, and formed a crust.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, you should dump them out. If you cook that you will right away smell the rotten blood coming out of it. But if you would like to make sure the only way to do it is to cook it and try a piece. Remember always cook your meat to 155 degrees to be safe that there is no bacteria left. 165 if possible.